# Android 4.1 - MediaRecorder Stop Does Nothing

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I've created a class to record sond with MediaRecorder. It starts recording without any problems, but when it runs the Stop command, it does nothing. No errors and exceptions are returned, but it doesn't stop recording, so the next time the class runs, start fails.

Heres my class:

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;


public class AudioRecorder {

    String Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    MediaRecorder mr = new MediaRecorder();
    Random generator = new Random();
    String File;
    String arq;


    public void startsRecording() {     

        //audio source = mic
        mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);       
        //format 3gp
        mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        //encoder
        mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        //Path
        arq = String.valueOf(generator.nextInt(1000)) + ".3gp";
        File = Path + "/" + arq;
        mr.setOutputFile(File);


        System.out.println("Started Recording: " + File);

        try {
            mr.prepare();
            mr.start();
            System.out.println("Start");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }       
    }


    public void stopsRecording() {      
        System.out.println("Stops Recording");
        if (mr != null) {
            System.out.println("Not null");
        try {
            System.out.println("Try");
            mr.stop();
            System.out.println("Stop");         

        }  catch(IllegalStateException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

         catch(RuntimeException r) {
             System.out.println("Error");            
             System.out.println(r.toString());
        }
           catch(Exception f){
                 System.out.println("Error");            
                 System.out.println(f.toString());
            }
        finally {
            mr.release();   
            System.out.println("Release");
            mr = null;

        }


        } else {

            System.out.println("IS null");

        }

    }



}
```

Here is the output:

```
01-29 12:39:15.258: I/System.out(702): Started Recording: /mnt/sdcard/619.3gp
01-29 12:39:15.469: I/System.out(702): Start    
01-29 12:39:27.458: I/System.out(702): Stops Recording
01-29 12:39:27.458: I/System.out(702): Not null
01-29 12:39:27.458: I/System.out(702): Try
```

And it does not do anything further.

In Android 2.3 that code works.

What could be the problem?

Edit: I'm declaring it in another class:

```
AudioRecorder AR = new AudioRecorder();
```

Then starting these methods with:

```
AR.startsRecording();
```

and

```
 AR.stopsRecording();
```

Comment: How are you calling this methods ?

Comment: I declare the class with:

`AudioRecorder AR = new AudioRecorder();`

Then call:

`AR.startsRecording();`

and afterwards,

`AR.stopsRecording();`

ps. how do I add new lines here?

Comment: There is a `edit` link in your question, click on it and add the code you want to add it.

Comment: Edited and added how I'm calling the methods